# Professional critiques

Tags: learning

I really want to improve my photography so I was thinking to buy a professional critiques for a famous photographer
I just saw that 100asa.com has just launched a professional critiques service
Have you every tried it ? Or any other services you would recommend?
Any suggestions are welcome here